# Nginx 502: Bad Gateway with rstudio server

Tags: nginx, docker, rstudio

Hi I'm trying to set up RStudio server with a reverse proxy.

Here is my Nginx config

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;

# Defines a file that will store the process ID of the main process.
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  # Sets the maximum number of simultaneous connections that can be opened by a worker process.
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server {

    # Running port
    listen 80;

    # Proxying the connections
    location /rstudio/ {
      rewrite ^/rstudio/(.*)$ /$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8787;
      proxy_redirect http://localhost:8787/ $scheme://$host/rstudio/;
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I get a 502: Bad Gateway error. Do you have any idea? 
8787 is open as reported from netstat

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::8787                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

RStudio and nginx is running on two separated docker container which have port opened

Comment: Nothing change adding/removing the slash

Answer (score -1):

There is a how-to documentation on the Rstudio website that details how to use either Nginx or Apache reverse proxies.

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552326-Running-RStudio-Server-with-a-Proxy

For nginx it suggests the following configuration :-

```
http {

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

server {
  listen 80;


  location /rstudio/ {
    rewrite ^/rstudio/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8787;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:8787/ $scheme://$host/rstudio/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_read_timeout 20d;
  }
```